# R readxl excel file with dollar sign

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I'm trying to read an excel file with some columns currency values, which contain dollar signs.
Looks like:
[image]

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("file.xlsx")
```

However this read the dollar sign columns as dttm but not dbl. How to solve this?
[image]

Comment: When I try this on test excel sheet that I created it reads it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`read_excel` tries to guess the col types, when nothing is specified (default is `col_types = NULL`)

you could specify some `col_types` and guess others

```
read_excel(datasets, col_types = c("guess", "text", "guess"))
```

In a second step you may need to remove the dollar sign and change it to numeric.